# Getting an exec format error on Linux (Chromebook) When i'm trying to install Prusaslicer

Tags: chromebook, appimage

I've been trying to install the program PrusaSlicer on my Chromebook. I have Linux installed and up and running. I'm able to get all the way to ./file step before I get an error.

```
~bash: ./PrusaSlicer-2.4.2+linux-x64-GTK3-202204251120.AppImage: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I would really like some help if anyone know what i'm doing not Right

Comment: What CPU does the chromebook have? I'm guessing you have a ARM CPU, and PrusaSlicer for x86_64.

Comment: i believe it is a MediaTek MTK8173C

Comment: So ARM as commented above. And this site is for Ubuntu and official derivatives only.

Comment: Prusa doesn't provide ARM version of PrusaSlicer. You may have a look at [this ARM appimage version](https://github.com/davidk/PrusaSlicer-ARM.AppImage), which seems reasonably up to date, but built for RPi CPU's, not your MediaTek CPU. YMMV.